# Where to store constants in DDD/Layered architecture

Tags: domain-driven-design, constants

for example, I have a `Media` entity, and it has `MediaType` value object, which responsible for holding/creating media type. What is the best place to store a list of possible media type constants? First what I can think it's to store inside of the `MediaType` as it's responsible for creating type. But what if I need it in the application layer, or in the interface layer to validate the request, or even in the query.

Looks like if I want to isolate domain, I can't store constants in the `MediaType` as  I can't use it outside of the domain. Or to use the constant only in the domain layer, and hardcode it everywhere else, seems incorrect for me as in such a case we do not have a single place to change it. The third option is to create separate constants class like `MediaConstants`and to store it outside of the domain (not sure where), but in such a case looks like we do not need `MediaType` VO at all.

What are the best practices of dealing with constants in the DDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolating your domain is, of course, what you are after.  This means that your domain contains all the relevant invariants and, as you have done, enumerations and the like that you need to make your domain model expressive.

Sometimes the "outside" world is going to require *duplication* of sorts to make things easier and more convenient.  For instance, the fact that your domain check that an e-mail address is in the correct format does not mean that your web front-end does not *also* perform that validation.  You *could* forego such an e-mail validation on the front-end but that is going to end up leaving the users with a rather poor experience.  We "duplicate" the validation on the front-end as a convenience.

The same goes for some data.  A generic approach for flat classification structures may be something like `ReferenceType` 1-* `ReferenceItem` where `ReferenceType.Name` is something like `MediaType` and `ReferenceItem.Name` is whatever values you require.  Sometimes you could have a `Code` and `IsSystemType` for your reference items but that is the general idea.  Each reference type would have one or more reference items so a rather simple *one-to-many* relationship that can be easily persisted to some data store.  You could then expose the values to your front-end via a query mechanism and in your integration layer/concern (web controller / message handler) you could take the relevant item name (or code) and map that to, say, your enumeration.

Comment: So you mean either duplicate constants or store them it the persistence storage? I need to think about that, but honestly, I do not like both ideas: 1. if I'm going to add new constants, I need do it on multiple places; 2. with persistent storage it's extra costs (mostly time) to get simple (immutable) data, I know I can cache it but still, faster is to use constants. But I agree that domain isolation is more important so I need to make a decision

Comment: I would typically "duplicate" the values by storing them in a database and using those for display purposes.  Many times the ids/codes would be used in related tables and then joined on for reporting/viewing and the like.  Domain objects do not lend themselves well to querying.  That goes for all domain objects, not just enumerations.  But yes, you are going to have to pick your poison :)

Comment: but what if I have a query like get all media with a certain type in such a case I still need to hardcode the type in the where clause. I know constant should be never changed so I should not worry that I need to change it in different places, but even in case of code autocompletion, I need to remember al the types, when it's easier to call MediaType::SOME_TYPE

Comment: Your infrastructure layer usually has access to your domain given that it has to save/read aggregates via the repository implementations.  I usually then use the relevant enumeration.  In C# the enumeration base type is typically `int` so the actual id would be a cast `(int)MediaType.Pdf` which would then be a simple integer.  A query layer may *not* necessarily have access to your domain and there I simply use the actual id given that it is a fixed value.  I may even pass that in and then the caller may have access to the domain and do the casting.  YMMV